# Reversing dictionary key to value and vice-versa python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

```
a_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'thee': 3, 'four': 4}
new_dict = {}
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    new_dict[value] = key

print(new_dict) #result will be as below
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'thee', 4: 'four'}
```

I am just wondering why the result of the new_dict is not:

`{'one': 'one', 'two': 'two', 'three': 'three', 'four': 'four'}`

I used this to reverse the key and values, but since in the iteration we changing the 'values' with 'key', I didn't understand why the value of the 'key' was changed.

Comment: Why _would_ the result be that, in your opinion?

Comment: Just print out `key` and `value` in the for-loop.

Comment: To get that output you would need to write *new_dict[key] = key* Does that help you to see what's happening? Also, bear in mind that "reversing" a dictionary in this way is not necessarily reversible - i.e., dictionary A is reversed to B then B is reversed to A. The new A may not be the same as the original A. Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your `for-loop` from:

```
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    new_dict[value] = key
```

to

```
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    new_dict[key] = key
```

**Reason**: `new_dict` is a new dictionary its keys will be from the keys of `a_dict` and it values will also be the keys from `a_dict`.

---

```
a_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'thee': 3, 'four': 4}
new_dict = {}
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    new_dict[key] = key

print(new_dict) #result will be as below
{'one': 'one', 'two': 'two', 'thee': 'thee', 'four': 'four'}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, what you are asking is where are we actually SWAPPING the keys and values from the original to the new dictionary, since it "seems" like we are only assigning the keys to this new dict.

```
new_dict[value] = key
```

## Explanation

This is because you don't need to declare anything explicitly to create a key in a `dict`. The key is created when you are doing the assignment itself. To elaborate -

- In the following code, the `new_dict[value]` is the part where you are creating the key inside this new dictionary using the values of the original one.
- And, the `new_dict[value]=key` is where you are actually assigning this key's value as the key from the original dictionary.

This can be understood with a simple print statement -

```
a_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
new_dict = {}
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    print(f"For ORIGINAL Key, Value as {key, value}")
    print(f"Current state of NEW dict is {new_dict}")
    print('---------------------')
    new_dict[value] = key
```

```
For ORIGINAL Key, Value as ('one', 1)
Current state of NEW dict is {}
---------------------
For ORIGINAL Key, Value as ('two', 2)
Current state of NEW dict is {1: 'one'}
---------------------
For ORIGINAL Key, Value as ('three', 3)
Current state of NEW dict is {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
---------------------
For ORIGINAL Key, Value as ('four', 4)
Current state of NEW dict is {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

---

This is equivalent to the following -

```
a_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
new_dict = {}
for key, value in a_dict.items():

    new_dict.setdefault(value)  # ASSIGN NEW KEY TO DICT

    print(f"> Key {value} added to NEW dictionary")
    print(f"State of NEW dictionary - {new_dict}")
    
    new_dict[value] = key       # UPDATE THIS KEY'S VALUE

    print(f"> Value updated to {value} for this key in NEW dictionary")
    print(f"State of NEW dictionary - {new_dict}")
    print("---------------")
```

```
> Key 1 added to NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: None}
> Value updated to 1 for this key in NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: 'one'}
---------------
> Key 2 added to NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: 'one', 2: None}
> Value updated to 2 for this key in NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
---------------
> Key 3 added to NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: None}
> Value updated to 3 for this key in NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
---------------
> Key 4 added to NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: None}
> Value updated to 4 for this key in NEW dictionary
State of NEW dictionary - {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'}
```

---

"Python Variable is containers that store values. Python is not “statically typed”. We do not need to declare variables before using them or declare their type. A variable is created the moment we first assign a value to it. A Python variable is a name given to a memory location. It is the basic unit of storage in a program." - [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-variables/).

Answer (score 0):

```
a_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'thee': 3, 'four': 4}
new_dict = {}
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    new_dict[key] = key

print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a dictionary with identical keys and values is probably nonsense. Please give more context to help you or study [data structure in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Here is the proper way to initialize a dictionary in python: you pass it a list of tuple with (key, value). A convenient way to do this is to use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to combine a list of keys together with a list of values. Since you want only keys, simply pass two times the list of keys to `zip()`. Here is an example:

```
>>> a_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'thee': 3, 'four': 4}
>>> dict(zip(a_dict.keys(), a_dict.keys()))
{'one': 'one', 'two': 'two', 'thee': 'thee', 'four': 'four'}
```

in case you really need to invert keys and values as stated in the title of your question you can do the following:

```
>>> dict(zip(a_dict.values(), a_dict.keys()))
{'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'thee', '4': 'four'}
```